# Subtract minute from DateTime in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2005, dateadd

Suppose I have a datetime field whose value is **2000-01-01 08:30:00** 
and a duration field whose value is say **00:15** (meaning 15 minutes)

If I subtract these two, I should get **2000-01-01 08:15:00**

Also if I want to subtract **1:15** (means 1 hour 15 minutes), the output should be **2000-01-01 07:15:00**

I am trying `SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '00:15','2000-01-01 08:30:00');`

But the output is 52595055. How can i get the desired result?

N.B.~ If I do `SELECT dateadd(minute, -15,'2000-01-01 08:30:00');` , I will get the desired result but that involves parsing the minute field.

Edit:

As per the answers, every one is suggesting converting everything into minutes and then to subtract - so if it is 1:30, i need to subtract 90 minutes. That's fine. Any other way without converting to minutes?

Comment: You'd have been better off to store full DATETIME values for start and end

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, -15, '2000-01-01 08:30:00');
```

The second value (-15 in this case) must be numeric (i.e. not a string like '00:15'). If you need to subtract hours and minutes I would recommend splitting the string on the : to get the hours and minutes and subtracting using something like

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, -60 * @h - @m, '2000-01-01 08:30:00');
```

where @h is the hour part of your string and @m is the minute part of your string

EDIT:

Here is a better way:

```
SELECT CAST('2000-01-01 08:30:00' as datetime) - CAST('00:15' AS datetime)
```

Comment: I am sorry but I was editing while you posted the answer. I donot want to parse that.

Comment: So you mean to say that to convert everything into minutes and then to subtract like if it is 1:30 means i need to subtract 90 minutes. That's fine. Any other way without converting to minutes?

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer after I realised I hadn't provided a very good solution; multiplying by 1440 (the number of minutes in a day) converts days to minutes. Previously I was casting a datetime to a float to get a number representing days hence the conversion.. I have since changed my answer so that it does not require conversion to minutes at all

Answer (score 6):

You want to use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx), using a negative duration. e.g.

```
DATEADD(minute, -15, '2000-01-01 08:30:00')
```

Comment: So you mean to say that to convert everything into minutes and then to subtract like if it is 1:30 means i need to subtract 90 minutes. That's fine. Any other way without converting to minutes?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, -15,'2000-01-01 08:30:00')
```

*DATEDIFF is the difference between 2 dates.*

Comment: So you mean to say that to convert everything into minutes and then to subtract like if it is 1:30 means i need to subtract 90 minutes. That's fine. Any other way without converting to minutes?

Answer (score 2):

I spent a while trying to do the same thing, trying to subtract the `hours:minutes` from `datetime` - here's how I did it:

```
convert( varchar, cast((RouteMileage / @average_speed) as integer))+ ':' +  convert( varchar, cast((((RouteMileage / @average_speed) - cast((RouteMileage / @average_speed) as integer)) * 60) as integer)) As TravelTime,

dateadd( n, -60 * CAST( (RouteMileage / @average_speed) AS DECIMAL(7,2)), @entry_date) As DepartureTime
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
DeliveryDate                TravelTime             DepartureTime
2012-06-02 12:00:00.000       25:49         2012-06-01 10:11:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to pull apart your interval, and [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) to subtract the parts:

```
select dateadd(
     hh,
    -1 * datepart(hh, cast('1:15' as datetime)),
    dateadd(
        mi,
        -1 * datepart(mi, cast('1:15' as datetime)),
        '2000-01-01 08:30:00'))
```

or, we can convert to minutes first (though OP would prefer not to):

```
declare @mins int
select @mins = datepart(mi, cast('1:15' as datetime)) + 60 * datepart(hh, cast('1:15' as datetime)) 
select dateadd(mi, -1 * @mins, '2000-01-01 08:30:00')
```

Comment: So you mean to say that to convert everything into minutes and then to subtract like if it is 1:30 means i need to subtract 90 minutes. That's fine. Any other way without converting to minutes?