# update sql server datetime field

Tags: sql-server, database

I already have data inserted in table with column of datetime named enddate. I want to update the all rows to have

```
 enddate = enddate - 1 minute.
```

How i can do this?

Thanks
Samer

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309028/subtract-minute-from-datatime-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET enddate = DATEADD(minute, -1, enddate)
```

detail [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)